# Photo Gallery z-index issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, z-index, photo-gallery

I am trying to modify the z-index of the http://tympanus.net/Development/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/ . The demo I am refering to is in the third / final example shown.

When the polaroid is flipped I am unable to select the text in chrome or Safari, but I can in firefox.

Chrome and Firefox
[image]

I just need a way to be able to select the text in chrome/safari. This way I can then be able to add hyperlinks and call to action buttons that are currently hidden behind the z-index.

The div in question is 'photostack-back'

HTML

```
<section id="photostack-1" class="photostack photostack-start">
<div>
    <!-- Polaroid with backside -->
    <figure>
        <a href="http://goo.gl/fhwlSP" class="photostack-img">
            <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="img02"/>
        </a>
        <figcaption>
            <h2 class="photostack-title">Happy Days</h2>
            <!-- optional backside -->
            <div class="photostack-back">
                <p>Fish don't fry in the kitchen and beans don't burn on the grill. Took a whole lotta tryin' just to get up that hill. Baby if you've ever wondered - wondered whatever became of me. </p>
            </div>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
   </div>
</section
```

CSS

```
.photostack-back {
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: #fff;
font-family: "Give You Glory", cursive;
color: #a7a0a2;
padding: 50px 40px;
text-align: left;
font-size: 22px;
line-height: 1.25;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is the tutorial [Scattered Polaroids Gallery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/28/scattered-polaroids-gallery/)

Comment: What about posting the CSS as well?

Comment: Thanks @Hoshts , I have updated my code

Comment: I can see the problem. Mobile safari got the same problem with selecting the text. I'm currently on mobile so can't look into it. Will check back when I'm at computer again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that this was not a z-index issue but a backface-visibility issue.

I used [veinjs](https://github.com/israelidanny/veinjs) to inject the following code in photostack.js

```
vein.inject('figure', {'backface-visibility' : 'visible !important'});
```

and the css

```
figcaption {
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```